# Why does this Python code show me a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" after executing without any problems?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

My Code works just fine, but there is always an error at the end after everything was executed. And since I am a beginner I do not know why xD. Would be really cool if someone could help, I am just feeling really stupid right now xD.
Thanks a lot in advance (:
Here is also the complete Error message it shows:

Your cards: [8, 9], current score: 17

Computer's first card: 5

Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y

Your cards: [8, 9, 3], current score: 20

Computer's first card: 5

Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y

Your cards: [8, 9, 3, 9], current score: 29

Computer's first card: 5

Your final hand: [8, 9, 3, 9], final score: 29

Computer's final hand: [5, 3], final score: 8

You went over. You lose

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

  File "main.py", line 120, in <module>
    game()
  File "main.py", line 108, in game
    checks_who_wins(total_score_player, added_cards_value(cards_computer)) 
  File "main.py", line 68, in checks_who_wins
    is_blackjack(added_cards_value_player, added_cards_value_computer)
  File "main.py", line 47, in is_blackjack
    if added_cards_value(list_name_player) == 21:
  File "main.py", line 43, in added_cards_value
    list_add = sum(list_name)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable




from art import logo 
import random
from replit import clear


def eleven_card(cards_list_porc):
    a = random.randint(0,12)
    if a == 11:
        b = 21 - added_cards_value(cards_list_porc) 
        return b 
    return a

def added_cards_value(list_name):
    # """Calculate and adds every element of the list"""
    # list_add = 0
    # for x in range(0,len(list_name) ):
    #     list_add += list_name[x] 
    list_add = sum(list_name)
    return list_add

def is_blackjack(list_name_player, list_name_computer):
    if added_cards_value(list_name_player) == 21:
        print("Win with a Blackjack ")
        return "a"
    if added_cards_value(list_name_computer) == 21:
        print("Lose, opponent has Blackjack ")
        return "a"

def checks_who_wins(added_cards_value_player, added_cards_value_computer):
    if added_cards_value_player < 21 and added_cards_value_computer < 21:
        if added_cards_value_player > added_cards_value_computer:
            print("You win ") 
        if added_cards_value_player < added_cards_value_computer:
            print("You lose ")
        if added_cards_value_player == added_cards_value_computer:
            print("Draw ")
    if added_cards_value_player > 21:
        print("You went over. You lose ")
    if added_cards_value_computer > 21:
        print("Opponent went over. You win ")
    if added_cards_value_player == added_cards_value_computer:
            print("Draw ")
    is_blackjack(added_cards_value_player, added_cards_value_computer)

def end_program(cards_player, cards_computer):
    print(f"Your final hand: {cards_player}, final score: {added_cards_value(cards_player)} ")
    print(f"Computer's final hand: {cards_computer}, final score: {added_cards_value(cards_computer)} ")
    y = False

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
def game():
    play_decision = input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ")
    if play_decision == "n":
        return
    if play_decision == "y":
        clear()
        print(logo)

        cards_computer = []
        for x in range (1,3):
            cards_computer.append(cards[random.randint(0,12)])
        cards_player = []
        for x in range (1,3):
            cards_player.append(cards[random.randint(0,12)])
        total_score_player = added_cards_value(cards_player)
        print(f"Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total_score_player}")
        print(f"Computer's first card: {cards_computer[0]}")
        if is_blackjack(cards_player, cards_computer) == "a":
            game()
            return
        goes_on = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:")
        y = True

        while y == True:
            if goes_on == "y":
                cards_player.append(cards[eleven_card(cards_player)])
                total_score_player = added_cards_value(cards_player)
                print(f"Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total_score_player}")
                print(f"Computer's first card: {cards_computer[0]}")
                is_blackjack(cards_player, cards_computer)
                if total_score_player > 21: 
                    end_program(cards_player, cards_computer)
                    checks_who_wins(total_score_player, added_cards_value(cards_computer)) 
            if goes_on == "n":
                while added_cards_value(cards_computer) < 20:
                    cards_computer.append(cards[eleven_card(cards_computer)])
                end_program(cards_player, cards_computer)
                checks_who_wins(total_score_player, sum(cards_computer))  
            if total_score_player < 21 and goes_on == "y":
                goes_on = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:")
            else:  
                y = False
        game()

game()
```

Comment: Please provide a Complete Minimal Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example That way we can help you better. In a lot of cases, creating a ME already gives you the solution to your problem.

Comment: `list_name_player` isn't a list of values you can add up; it's a single integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears when your function `is_blackjack` is called:

```
is_blackjack(added_cards_value_player, added_cards_value_computer)
```

Here you pass the `added_cards_value`s (which are both integer), while the function expects a list of cards. In your code, the function expects the two list of cards and tries to calculate the `added_card_values` of them. So, change the function definition of `is_blackjack()` so that it does not try to calculate this sum again, since you already pass this sum:

```
def is_blackjack(added_cards_value_player, added_cards_value_computer):
    if added_cards_value_player == 21:
        print("Win with a Blackjack ")
        return "a"
    if added_cards_value_computer == 21:
        print("Lose, opponent has Blackjack ")
        return "a"
```

And you will be fine.